# Loop through unique values in a column to check another column and create another column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a function to go through each unique value in a column and check if another column contains a value and then create a column that shows the result.

For example: for each unique ID in df, check if the stats is A then create a result column:

df:

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |

new_df:

| ID | Status | Result A? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | YES |
| 2 | B | NO |

I started off with

```
def function(df):
  id = list(df['ID'].unique())
  status = ['A']
  for i in id:
```

If anyone can share some thoughts I would much appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated it with what I have but not sure how to get started from here

Comment: Are you sure the output you show is what you want? Why are there 2 rows for ID 1 but no rows for ID 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the rules correctly. Should I always take the first occurrence of the ID? Then the second row in your expected output is wrong.

You can use `numpy.where`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}, 'Status': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}})
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID"]).copy()
new_df["Result A?"] = np.where(new_df.Status == "A", "YES", "NO")
```

to get this:

```
   ID Status Result A?
0   1      A       YES
2   2      B        NO
```

Edit: Your desired output is ambiguous, two things you can do:

```
df.groupby("ID")["Status"].apply({"A"}.issubset).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}).rename("Result A?")
```

gives you:

```
ID
1    Yes
2     No
Name: Result A?, dtype: object
```

Or:

```
df["Result A?"] = np.where(df.groupby("ID")["Status"].apply({"A"}.issubset).loc[df.ID], "YES", "NO")
```

which gives you:

```
   ID Status Result A?
0   1      A       YES
1   1      B       YES
2   2      B        NO
3   2      C        NO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for kindly providing your input. No we shouldn't look at the first occurrence only. I.e. df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 'Status': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'A'}})
should result in YES and YES for both ID's.

Comment: I've edited my post to suggest two more solutions. In the first example, you create a Series with each ID and an identifier showing if A is in Status. In the second example you create a new column based on that.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, the second method with .apply was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5:3}, 'Status': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5:'B'}})
```

| index | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 3 | 2 | C |
| 4 | 2 | A |
| 5 | 3 | B |

```
df['Result A?'] = df['Status'].apply(lambda x: x=='A')
df['Result A?'] = df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')['Result A?'].any())
df['Result A?'] = df['Result A?'].map({True:'YES', False:'NO'})
```

| index | ID | Status | Result A? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | YES |
| 1 | 1 | B | YES |
| 2 | 2 | B | YES |
| 3 | 2 | C | YES |
| 4 | 2 | A | YES |
| 5 | 3 | B | NO |